# How host multiple asp.net sites on in IIS 6.0

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis-6, windows-server-2003

How I can configure two asp.net sites in IIS 6.0 to be accessible through internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `Windows 2003` `IIS6` supports multiple sites running simultaneously through the UI. You just have to make sure that you run them each with a [host header](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324287) to avoid conflicts when binding to the same port.

Answer (score 1):

create 2 sites with 2 different urls/ports and make sure port 80 is opened in your router/windows firewall